# Trouble creating a conda enviroment with numpy 10.1.2

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, conda

I'm having trouble getting numpy working with conda + python 2.7. It works fine with python 3, but when I try below I get "cannot import name scalarmath".

`conda create -n test numpy python=2.7 --no-default-packages`

`source activate test`

`python -c 'import numpy'`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import scalarmath
ImportError: cannot import name scalarmath`

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate your environment with `source activate test`. This works for me on OS X 10.9.:

```
conda create -n test numpy python=2.7 --no-default-packages
source activate test
python -c 'import numpy'
```

Comment: I didn't add that step in there but you can see that it's activated in the output '/Users/me/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py' i'll update.

Comment: Did you try opening a new shell window and work from there?