# Install librec python

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I can't install `librec` for Python. In PyCharm I can't find librec in the list and whith pip I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Young>pip install librec
Collecting librec
  Using cached librec-0.0.5.tar.gz (855 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Young\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tr3zjrfg\\librec\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Young\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tr3zjrfg\\librec\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Young\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-2ynrvbse'
         cwd: C:\Users\Young\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tr3zjrfg\librec\
    Complete output (3 lines):
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:138: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
      from . import _distributor_init
    Please install numpy>=1.16.4 first.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Could you try `pip install numpy --upgrade`

Comment: Thakyou bout : C:\Users\Young>pip install numpy --upgrade
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.20.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (13.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 13.7 MB 726 kB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.2
    Uninstalling numpy-1.19.2:
           ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.19.2.dist-info\\direct_url.json'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Ok so you should put your code and output between \`\`

Comment: Ok so you should use the cmd with administrator right

Comment: New error : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement librec (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.4, 0.0.5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for librec

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962703/how-to-get-numpy-working-properly-in-anaconda-python-3-7-6