# I can not find a package in pycharm Interpreter for installation

Tags: pycharm, package, interpreter

[image]

I can not find the librec package to install.why???!

Comment: Send `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...** to PyCharm support at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com Does `pip install librec` work for this interpreter in the terminal?

Comment: pip install librec gives an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67707571/install-librec-python

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found was: Because I wanted to install that package in Anaconda, I could not.
Because only the libraries on this list can be installed in Anaconda.
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64/